# Counting occurrences of a value in multiple columns - postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `fixtures` (I have simplified for this example) and would like to populate the last two columns (*_plus_mc_per) with the percentage of times occurred for each number with a query run against the `mc_*` columns. It would look like this as an example

```
#mc = Match Corner # mc_per = Match Corner Percentage
| mc_0 | mc_1 | mc_3 | mc_4 | match_count | one_plus_mc_per | two_plus_mc_per |
| 1    | 4    | 3    | null | 3           | 100             |  66             |
```

At the point where I run my query it looks like

```
 #mc = Match Corner # mc_per = Match Corner Percentage
| mc_0 | mc_1 | mc_3 | mc_4 | match_count | one_plus_mc_per | two_plus_mc_per |
| 1    | 4    | 3    | null | 3           | null            |  null           |
```

So starting with the query for `one_plus_mc_per` I can do this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fixtures WHERE coalesce(mc_0,0) >= 1 AND id = 182; 
# Using coalesce for dealing with null, will return a 0 if value null
```

This returns

```
| count |
| 1     |
```

If I run this query on each column individually the results returned would be

```
| count | count | count | count | 
| 1     | 1     | 1     | 0     |
```

Thus enabling me to add all the column values up and divide by my match count. This makes sense (and I thank dmfay for getting me to think about his suggestion in a previous question)

My problem is I can't run this query 4 times for example as that is very ineffective. My SQL fu is not strong and was looking for a way to do this in one call to the database, enabling me to then take that percentage value and update the percentage column

Thanks

Comment: you probably can use window functions over different windows for it. build env in rextester or db-fiddle  to demo

Comment: could you update the question with more details about the structure & contents of the `fixtures` table.

Comment: @HaleemurAli sure, but what would you like to know?

Comment: i don't get how one_plus_mc_per is 100 and two_plus_mc_per is 66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_0,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_1,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_3,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_4,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_4,
FROM 
    fixtures 
WHERE  id = 182;
```

It will return count of all the columns in single query

I am not sure though, whats the use of `id = id` in your query as it will always be true.

If you want count of columns *_mc for every row with `> 0` condition, try this:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_0,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_1,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_3,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_4,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count
FROM 
    fixtures 
WHERE  id = 182;
```

UPDATE:

Calculating `one_plus_mc_per`

```
SELECT 
    CAST((CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_0,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_1,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_3,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN coalesce(mc_4,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS DECIMAL)/match_count as one_plus_mc_per
FROM 
    fixtures 
WHERE  id = 182;
```

Comment: Thanks @RahulJain , the id was literally meant to mean the id of the fixture, I've updated the question. That returns exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. I guess I can take that returned value and just have another query that divides by match count or can I do that in the same query also ?

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it suffice your requirement.

Comment: Will do, just waiting for sufficient time to pass :-) .... Any thoughts on my question above ?

Comment: I didn't got you here. How are you calculating `one_plus_mc_per`? example would help.

Comment: It will be the result of count divided by the column `match_count`

Comment: So, in your example, there is a column named `match_count` bot what is the `count` value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171673/discussion-between-richlewis-and-rahul-jain).

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has very nice capabilities for answering this type of question:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mc_0 >= 1) as count_0,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mc_1 >= 1) as count_1,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mc_3 >= 1) as count_3,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mc_4 >= 1) as count_4,
       AVG ( (mc_0 >= 1)::int + (mc_1 >= 1)::int + (mc_3 >= 1)::int + (mc_4 >= 1)::int
           ) as one_plus_mc_per
FROM fixtures 
WHERE id = 182;
```

The `FILTER` is ANSI-standard syntax.  The conversion of booleans to numbers is a very convenient construct.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I will look at this aswell, is there any difference to the above answer?

Comment: @Richlewis . . . `FILTER` can be more efficient.  The use of the boolean-->integer conversion definitely simplifies the code.